# Need help with finding the surface integral of the hyperbolic paraboloid bounded by an elliptic cylinder

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Trying to find out the surface area of a pringle. I graphed the shape on geogebra 3D.

[Pringle Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXKd5.png)

I found the equation for the hyperbolic paraboloid to be $z=\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{3y^2}{19}$ And the equation for the bounding elliptic cylinder to be $x^2+\frac{5y^2}{8}=4$

I know that to find the Surface area you must use the integral $$\int \int \sqrt{1+(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x})^{2}+(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y})^{2}} dA$$

I tried my best to solve it using the two equations i got from graphing but no luck. This is for a school assignment (we have not learned multivariable calculus or even gone near it). I managed to solve for the surface area when I simplified the equations to $z=\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{y^2}{4}$ and $x^{2}+y^{2}=6$

Finding the limits was not difficult for the simplified functions because $x^{2}+y^{2}=6$ is a circle with radius $\sqrt{6}$ The surface integral I got after subbing in the limits and solving the partial derivatives was $$\int_{0 }^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{6}}\sqrt{1+\frac{x^{2}}{4}+\frac{y^{2}}{4}}dA$$

Then by changing the integral from cartesian to polar coordinates dA becomes $rdrd\theta$ and applying $r^{2}=x^{2}+y^{2}$, the above integral is written as $$\int_{0 }^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{6}}\sqrt{1+\frac{r^{2}}{4}}rdrd\theta$$

Using $u=1+\frac{r^{2}}{4}$ as a substitution and changing the limits, I got

$$\sqrt{6}\int_{0 }^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{5}{2}}\sqrt{u}dud\theta$$

Then solving this integral is pretty straightforward i got $30.30cm^{2}$ as the surface area.

Im not really satisfied with my work though (I hope its correct, my draft hasn't been marked yet), it's good enough for the school assignment as I chose the topic myself and my teacher anyway expected me to simplify or change the topic entirely because it's too difficult. But for my own personal knowledge I'd like to know how to solve for the surface area of the actual shape, without any simplifications.

If anyone could help me do that using the two equations i got from the geogebra 3D graph, that would be much appreciated

Comment: I managed to parametrize the elliptic cylinder and i got $a=2$ and $b=\sqrt{6.4}$. So I got the parameters $x=2\theta cos \theta$ and $y=\sqrt{6.4}\theta sin \theta$. However, I can't find the limits of integration in terms of r because r changes with theta since it's an elliptic cylinder. Please help me